# Game of Thrones: What happened to Jon Umber?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I am a watcher of Game of Thrones (I have **not** read the books) and I was wondering what happened to the Jon Umber character? (The guy who was one of Robb Stark's bannermen in season one who got his fingers bit off by Robb's dire wolf — "your meat is bloody tough"). I noticed after season 1 he pretty much disappeared from the TV show.

In the book, does he die somehow? I noticed at the end of season 3, Osha and Rickon head to The Last Hearth (seat of House Umber) for refuge, so I'm wondering if maybe he'll appear again later in the series?

I guess I'm just wondering if the answer is the following:

1. he dies in the books and in the show they didn't bother to mention it. (If so, where does he die?)
2. I should expect him to appear again later in the show
3. it's unknown

This answer to this question could be a tad bit spoilerish for those that don't want to know what happened to him, so I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me how to mark this before answering it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The actor who played Jon "Greatjon" Umber, Clive Mantle couldn't do seasons 2 and 3 due to [scheduling conflicts](http://winteriscoming.net/2012/07/filming-on-season-three-begins-today/#comment-200823), which is why he disappeared from the TV show.

In the books:

> he was at the Red Wedding, survived and was a captive of the Freys. He is mentioned somewhat in A Feast for Crows and A Dance with Dragons, there is detail on his [wikia page](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Greatjon_Umber) if you want it.

Answer (score 10):

In Season 6, Smalljon revealed to Ramsay that

> [Great Jon Umber had died in the intervening time](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Jon_Umber_(Greatjon)#Season_6).